# Where should I ask "How to explain numerical modeling to a class of 7-16 year old kids?"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**On which SE site should I ask the below question?**

---

> I have little experience in teaching young kids. Soon, I will present my research to a class of 7 to 16 year old kids. I mainly do individual-based simulations in population genetics to investigate various evolutionary processes. I also do some Approximate Bayesian Computation.
>
> How should I go about **explaining the general reason why one would do numerical modeling?** I was thinking about starting with the concept of thought experiment and how we can, in our head simulate something without actually performing the action in the real world. Then, I would go toward more complicated thought experiment explaining that there is a point where our mind and intuition aren't powerful enough and we must let a computer do the thought experiment for us. I would say something like "I imagine a world, chose a set of rules that dictate this world and let the computer make the thought experiment in this world".
>
> Can you give me some advice or even a guideline for the narrative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems a bit broad for now, but might be on-topic for [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) if edited to include specific examples.

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with teaching mathematics
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

You should review their Help Center and edit your question down to concrete teaching examples, and where you think your shortcomings with your teaching plan are.  If anything, I would review MathEducators.SE (especially questions tagged [secondary-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secondary-education)) for similar questions about teaching children.

Comment: Their meta might be interesting as well, for example: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/453/5933